# Azure virtual machine underlined hardware replacement

Tags: azure

My Azure VM is experiencing disk drive errors. Lot of messages "The IO operation at logical block address XXX for Disk 1 was retried" appeared in the event log and services fail because of IO timeouts. It seems underlined hardware is failing. Is it possible to migrate VM somehow so VM will use another underlined hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During hardware failure, Azure infrastructure would automatically reprovision the VM - however, to try handling it proactively you would want to open a support ticket from Azure management portal.

Comment: I was expecting this but it seems it did not work well. I restarted VM couple of times but this did not help. Powering off and start VM seems solved the issue.